# iAd delegate does not work.

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but can't seem to get the `iAd` delegate to work.

This is a test I was doing to see what was involved in getting iAds running on.
`bannerAdViewController.xib` is a blank view with one single iAd at the top and I have connected the outlet to the ad.

I understand how to move it offscreen, but can't seem to get this simple test running so that it calls the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` or `bannerViewDidLoadAd`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW I am using xcode 4.

Here is what I have inside my bannerAdViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface bannerAdViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;
}
@end
```

contents of bannerAdViewController.m

```
#import "bannerAdViewController.h"

@implementation bannerAdViewController

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"NO BANNER AD");
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"AD IS LOADED");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the delegate of the `adView` to be the controller?

Comment: Let me start by saying that I am new to this stuff. Are you talking about setting the delegate via IB or in code? When I ad something like a Picker or Table View inside IB I can see where to set it's delegate. With an iAd I don't see that option. I just changed the viewDidLoad to alloc & init my adView iboutlet and then did a adView.delegate = self. I now get messages from the NSLogs inside the bannerViewDidLoadAd. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Beginners sometimes hit a wall when they realize that IB cannot solve all of your problems. While IB has a limited subset of what you can do, know that you can do EVERYTHING in a code based way. So if you don't see an option in IB, don't panic, you probably just have to implement it in code.

Comment: Thanks for your help coneybeare. I was watching the apple video called "Integrating ads with iAds" which used xcode 3. It showed how to assign the iAd delegate via IB. So is there still a way that you know of to do it via IB, or is that something they changed in xcode 4? PS checked out your twitter, in regards to this http://cloud.coneybeare.net/6kSP I like 1st row 2nd image & 2nd row 3rd image.

Comment: Sorry, I dont use IB at all so I cant help you there. I just know that if you want your controller to receive delegate messages, you have to set it as the delegate object. Thanks for the feedback on the image :)